I reduced a dataframe of times series, and now get "Error in replCmat4" and "Incompatible methods" error messages
I want to estimate a panel VAR model on a large set of data (130 companies, 6 variables, 2 identifiers over 10 years), so large I had to cut my sample by half to have enough memory to run the function.
This was the original code to organise the data and run a Panel VAR model:
# Reshape the company-specific variables (SR, CR, L) to long format
long_data <- stocks_logreturns %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Date, names_to = "Company", values_to = "SR") %>%
  left_join(CDS_normreturns %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Date, names_to = "Company", values_to = "CR"), by = c("Date", "Company")) %>%
  left_join(stocks_volchange %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Date, names_to = "Company", values_to = "L"), by = c("Date", "Company"))
  
# Add the macroeconomic variables (SPR, VIX, R) to the data
long_data <- long_data %>%
  left_join(SPY_returns, by = "Date") %>%
  rename(SPR = "S&P500 logreturns") %>%
  left_join(VIX_change, by = "Date") %>%
  rename(VIX = "VIX rate % change") %>%
  left_join(FED_change, by = "Date") %>%
  rename(R = "FED rate % change")
  
# Create a company ID for panelvar
long_data <- long_data %>%
  mutate(Company_ID = as.integer(as.factor(Company)))
  
# Prepare the panel data
panel_data <- pdata.frame(long_data, index = c("Company_ID", "Date"))

# Estimate the Panel VAR
# Here, p = 1 (lag order) based on your specification
model <- pvargmm(
  dependent_vars = c("SR", "CR"),  # Dependent variables
  lags = 1,        # Lag order for dependent variables
  exog_vars = c("SPR", "VIX", "R", "L"),  # Exogenous variables
  transformation = "fd",          # First-difference transformation
  data = panel_data,
  panel_identifier = c("Company_ID", "Date"),
  progressbar = TRUE
)

While it was working, it was extremely memory intensive, and even with 32Go Ram, I could not finish. As such I decided to only keep 5 years of data, and not 10.
So i simply decided to keep the data for the period I wanted (2018-01-01 to 2023-12-31), and created a new data frame for the period:
# Convert the Date column to Date format
panel_data$Date <- as.Date(panel_data$Date)

# Filter the dataframe for the desired date range
filtered_panel_data <- subset(panel_data, Date >= as.Date("2018-01-01") & Date <= as.Date("2023-12-31"))

But now, when I run the exact same function, with the new "filtered_panel_data" dataframe, I get the following error message:
Error in replCmat4(x, i1 = if (iMi) seq.int(from = 0L, length.out = di[1L]) else .ind.prep2(i,  : 
  nothing to replace with
In addition: Warning message:
In `[.data.frame`(Set_Vars_i, Set_Vars_i[, 2] == periods[j], dependent_vars) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.pseries") for "=="

I don't understand the issue, as I only removed the 5 years I didn't want, and didn't change anything else, so I would be grateful is someone could help me understand what is the problem(s?) here.

You did more than simply filter the data. You also converted one column (Date) to another format. You could maybe skip that step and try filtered_panel_data <- subset(panel_data, as.Date(Date) >= as.Date("2018-01-01") & as.Date(Date) <= as.Date("2023-12-31")). I am unable to test this myself.

Unfortunately I tried, and still got the same error results...
